# Get Json Feed for a Twitter Hashtag

Tags: c#, api, twitter, unity-game-engine

Hello I am currently working in Unity(C#) and am attempting to get a JSON feed from a certain hashtag on twitter. Yes I have done the authentication process and have all the tokens and keys. I have looked at plugins such as TweetSharp etc and have not been able to figure out how to simply get a JSON feed from a certain hashtag as stated in the API GET Status page

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

with there EXAMPLE RESULT being JSON and using a URL :

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23{HASHTAGHERE}

What else do I need to add on to this URL in order to get JSON Data back. I assume its a form of HTTP Headers.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to access the API yourself or do you want to have an example of a library to let you access the feed?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find a solution through this: https://stevenyau.wordpress.com/2013/12/26/working-with-twitter-api-1-1-with-unity/